# 3D Level Navigation Map for a 2D Mobile Game

Tags: 3d, unity, maps

I am currently making a game in which I want to create a level screen map. The Map doesn’t have to do anything with the game logic and stuff but I just want to add it to include a bit of richness. 
The Map I am planning to add will be a 3D map. I just want to know how I can use a 3D map for usage in a 2D game. What is the best approach to get started with? I have tried iTween’s Tweening stuff to Animate and control camera over a spline curve but I am not sure what can be the best approach for it?
The Map will be just a set of levels/point in which the initial need to clear before you go to the next.

Comment: What kind of movement does the player need to understand the map? In most games the map just pans and rotates around the central axis. For example the map in Fez: http://cdn2.pu.nl/media/misc2/fezmap.jpg

Comment: Hey Felsir! Thanks for your quick response. I am unable to see the image you attached.

Comment: Try Google image search on "fez game map".